# multidplyr within a for loop- warning: closing unused connections

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multidplyr

I'm running a loop within loop that subsets a large, sparse dataset and calculates mean and median for each lab variable within a 2,3 and 5 year search window. I'm getting a message "warning: closing unused connections"- is it because multidplyr is unable to use other cores when it's inside a loop?

my code looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello. Please cut'n'paste code as plain text. You can use code chunks on SO. Screenshots are inaccessible to some folks, they're hard to read for others, they're non-searchable, and you cannot cut'n'paste from them. All these things lowers your chances for someone to help you.

Comment: i would really like to- but i'm connected remotely and can't copy the code without a document release process that usually takes two weeks... unless you know a quick tool that extracts text (code formatting) from screenshots?

Comment: Even on a remote connection you might be able to get a reproductible example using the {reprex} package: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/